# Fragment getting closed after on activity result call

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragments A and B. A contains a list and B has an imageview. when i click on a list item in fragment A it goes to B. I'm calling camera and gallery intent from B.

In B

```
alert.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    if (item == 0) {
     Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
       android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    } else if (item == 1) {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
    } else {
     dialog.cancel();
    }

   }
  });
```

onActivityResult in B

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
   if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    cameraIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result has been cancelled!",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
   try {
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
     try {
      stream = getActivity().getContentResolver()
        .openInputStream(data.getData());
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
     cameraIcon
       .setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
         bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
         bitmap.getHeight() / 2, true));

    } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result has been cancelled!",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
  }
 }
```

But some times after the intent collects the image  and comes to onActivityResult fragment B 
get closed and goes to fragment A instead of setting the image to the image view in fragment B.....

What am i doing wrong please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check using another device.I think the device issue.

Comment: Exactly luttu!! that was the problem..it works fine with other devices....thanks a lot for you time....

Comment: Well, the key to successful android development is knowning those issues and knowing how to bypass them. The result of blaming the unwanted behaviour onto 'the other device' is potentially many owners of 'those other devices' will simply reject your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I would say an exception is being thrown in fragment B after onActivityResult has finished.. perhaps you should check your event log/trace the events in the onResume/createView etc.